# Is there a resource that explains ANN with simplicity?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have seen many websites and blogs explain ANNs (Artificial Neural Networks), but none take into account a step by step procedure of developing a base for people who do not know much about ANNs', instead they throw in a lot of mathematics, which unfortunately for me looks very elusive. Are there any websites/blogs that, say, teach a simple ANN program that can recognize computer generated digits or something even more simple than digits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This my annotated list of the best introductory (but complete) resources on **ANN** (aka *MLP*).

[Course Notebook, Willamette University](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/intro.html) This resource is about 25-30 pages total (navigate among the sections using the sidebar on the upper right of this page or by clicking *next* or *previous* at the bottom of a given page). I think so highly of this resource for two reasons (i) it contains a large number of diagrams and nicely integrates them with prose; and (ii) it's *comprehensive*--architecture of the network, the calculus that underlies back-propagation, selecting/iterating the training parameters (momentum, learning rate), etc. The [section on back-propagation](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/Backprop/backprop.html) (the computational and programmatic crux of ANN/MLP) is particularly good--combining prose, network diagrams, and the actual equations, it meticulously explains each step in a single epoch that comprises the training phase.

[IBM developer works class on neural networks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-neural/) This one, by David Mertz, contains working code (python) and a non-trivial data set. With the exception of the first few paragraphs, the entire document closely follows the code and data. To me, this is crucial, because unless i can code it, i don't think i have learned it (that's a personal threshold, might not work for others). Aside from that, the focus on code and interaction of that code with a supplied data set keeps the discussion practically grounded. Finally, the authors David Mertz and Andrew Blais, obviously have a strong command of the subject matter.

[Generation5](http://www.generation5.org/content/2004/MultiBP.asp) This is the most basic of the three, so perhaps the one to start with. The author is obviously knowledgeable of the minutiae of multi-layers perceptrons but doesn't require such knowledge of the reader--i.e., he explains back-propagation as a common-sense solution to a problem, without deferring to the numerical solution techniques (which is common in many references on MLP--'backprop is solved via gradient descent'). And like the first resource i mentioned, this one relies heavily on diagrams. Rather than data, (0's and 1's), the author discusses the structure and function of a MLP in the context of a simple predictive analytics scenario, using prose rather than reducing the problem to numerical data.

Comment: Thanks for the lovely references!